# Group by Date Difference of Period in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is by DB Table Structure

| cardNo | AccNo | ActiveDate | LastChargeDate | ExpiryDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXX1702 | 154505100 | 01-05-2013 | 02-06-2020 | 28-02-2021 |
| XXX2148 | 41805 | 01-05-2013 | 02-06-2020 | 28-02-2021 |
| XXX2694 | 4844404 | 01-05-2013 | 02-06-2020 | 28-02-2021 |
| XXX6634 | 44804844888 | 01-05-2013 | 02-06-2020 | 28-02-2021 |
| XXX7160 | 80445540 | 01-05-2013 | 02-06-2020 | 28-02-2021 |

Here is my SQL Query

```
 SELECT c.accno,
       5.00
       AS Charge,
       Concat('CARD XX', RIGHT(c.cardno, 4), ' AMC ', Upper(
       Format(c.lastchargedate, 'MMM')),
       Format(c.lastchargedate, 'yy'), ' ', 'to ',
       Upper(Format(Getdate(), 'MMM')), Format(CONVERT(DATE, Getdate()), 'yy'))
       AS
       Period,
       c.lastchargedate,
       c.activedate
FROM   cc c
WHERE  c.lastchargedate IS NOT NULL
       AND Datediff(day, c.lastchargedate, CONVERT(DATE, Getdate())) >= 365
```

The result is below.

```
PrimaryAccount  Charge  Period                          LastChargeDate  ActiveDate
104011192124    180.00  CARD XX9912 AMC MAR20 to MAR21  2020-03-03  2018-02-21
104011206784    180.00  CARD XX7122 AMC MAR20 to MAR21  2020-03-03  2019-02-04
104011266381    180.00  CARD XX8064 AMC MAR20 to MAR21  2020-03-03  2017-02-09
104011150218    180.00  CARD XX8775 AMC MAR20 to MAR21  2020-03-03  2017-02-17
104011262467    180.00  CARD XX0510 AMC APR18 to MAR21  2018-04-09  2018-03-21
```

The Last Record is showing APR 18 TO MAR 21 AND CHARGE IS ONLY 5

TOTAL DAYS: 1076 days HENCE, CHARGES SHOULD BE 2 TIMES 1076/365=2.94 AFTER CAST(2.946 AS INT)

How to take charge twice if days are more than 365 i.e. if the period is APR 18 TO MAR 21 then APR 18 TO MAR 20 and APR 20 TO MAR 21 etc

i.e.

```
104011262467    180.00  CARD XX0510 AMC APR18 to MAR21  2018-04-09  2018-03-21
```

should be like below result

```
104011262467    180.00  CARD XX0510 AMC APR18 to MAR19  2018-04-09  2018-03-21
104011262467    180.00  CARD XX0510 AMC APR19 to MAR20  2018-04-09  2018-03-21
104011262467    180.00  CARD XX0510 AMC APR20 to MAR21  2018-04-09  2018-03-21
```

Comment: Check your result with your query, that's different with your query

Comment: I think we are going to need you to show the output you'd like to get. As your post stands the answer from @Annamalia looks like the sorry of thing you are asking for but your comment on response suggests a requirement you haven't stated, at least not clearly.

Comment: @SteveLovell Edited expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just multiply the charge by the number of years, this will work for all scenarios

```
SELECT c.accno,
       5.00 * FLOOR(Datediff(day, c.lastchargedate, CONVERT(DATE, Getdate()))/365)
       AS Charge,
       Concat('CARD XX', RIGHT(c.cardno, 4), ' AMC ', Upper(
       Format(c.lastchargedate, 'MMM')),
       Format(c.lastchargedate, 'yy'), ' ', 'to ',
       Upper(Format(Getdate(), 'MMM')), Format(CONVERT(DATE, Getdate()), 'yy'))
       AS
       Period,
       c.lastchargedate,
       c.activedate
FROM   cc c
WHERE  c.lastchargedate IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Yes I can but I have to list entries separated by period

Comment: Edited the result

Answer (score 0):

We can use `CROSS APPLY` with a nested `VALUES` and a `WHERE` to split out the rows:

```sql
SELECT c.accno,
       5.00 AS Charge,
       Concat(
         'CARD XX',
         RIGHT(c.cardno, 4)
         ' AMC ',
         Upper(Format(v.StartDate, 'MMM')),
         Format(v.StartDate, 'yyMMM'),
         ' to ',
         Upper(Format(v.EndDate, 'MMM')),
         Format(v.EndDate, 'yy')
       ) AS Period,
       c.lastchargedate,
       c.activedate
FROM   cc c

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        DATEADD(day, v.StartDay, c.lastchargedate) AS StartDate,
        DATEADD(day, v.EndDay, c.lastchargedate) AS EndDate
    FROM
    (VALUES
      (0,365),
      (366,730),
      (731,1095),
      (1096,1460),
      (1461,1825)
    ) AS v(startDay, EndDay)
    WHERE Datediff(day, c.lastchargedate, CONVERT(DATE, Getdate())) <= v.EndDay
) AS v

WHERE  c.lastchargedate IS NOT NULL
       AND Datediff(day, c.lastchargedate, CONVERT(DATE, Getdate())) >= 365
```

What this does is *apply* to every row a nested table, containing all rows from the inner `v` which are within the amount of days we need. We then calculate the exact start and end dates, and use those instead in the final output.

Comment: When count of days are null then 'CARD XX0031 AMC JUN20 to MMMyy'